# R - Calculating mean over rolling window of 4 weeks for multiple variables, over multiple years, and over multiple brands in R - panel data

Tags: r, average, mean, rolling-computation

I have a panel dataset over several years over multiple brands. Each brand has 52 weekly observations and several numeric columns which I would like to get the 4 week average off (so week 1 gets the mean of week 1:4, week 2 gets the mean of week 2:5, etc. This means the last 3 weeks of the 52 for each brand in a year do not get any values, which is fine).

I have put some code which replicates the data in a simple way at the bottom.

I've tried to write some functions, but am nowhere close. The issue is that the function should distinguish between brands and years and takes the weeknumber into account and I cannot figure it out....

Thanks so much in advance!

[what I would like - simplified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c409Q.png)

```
#rm(list = ls())

week <- seq(from=1, to=52, by=1) 
col1 <- seq(from=5, to= 5*52, by=5)
col2 <- seq(from=10, to= 10*52, by=10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(week, col1 ,col2))

df2 <- df
df$brand <- "brand a"
df2$brand <- "brand b"

df <- rbind(df, df2)


rm(week, col1, col2, df2)

df2 <- df
df2 <- df
df$year <- "2019"
df2$year <- "2020"

df <- rbind(df, df2)

rm(df2)
```

Comment: you must NOT NEVER-EVER_EVER incluse this line in your sample code `rm(list = ls())`. People who try to help you might lose their own data because of it... I commented it out of your code.. ALso, it is a literal example in the 9th circle of the R-inferno (https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. Will not include it again. As for the book, will check that one first next time. I did not know it existed. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) functions and the `rollmean` function from the [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

# Create data
df <- data.frame(week = rep(seq(from = 1, to = 52, by = 1), times = 4),
                 col1 = seq(from = 5, to = 5 * 52 * 4, by = 5),
                 col2 = seq(from = 10, to = 10 * 52 * 4, by = 10),
                 brand = rep(c("brand a", "brand b",
                               "brand a", "brand b"),
                             each = 52),
                 year = rep(2018:2019, each = 104))

# Group, calculate rolling means, ungroup
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(year, brand) %>% 
  mutate(rolling_col1 = rollmean(x = col1, k = 4, fill = NA, align = "left"),
         rolling_col2 = rollmean(x = col2, k = 4, fill = NA, align = "left")) %>% 
  ungroup()

df2
# A tibble: 208 x 7
#    week  col1  col2 brand    year rolling_col1 rolling_col2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1     5    10 brand a  2018         12.5           25
# 2     2    10    20 brand a  2018         17.5           35
# 3     3    15    30 brand a  2018         22.5           45
# 4     4    20    40 brand a  2018         27.5           55
# 5     5    25    50 brand a  2018         32.5           65
# 6     6    30    60 brand a  2018         37.5           75
# 7     7    35    70 brand a  2018         42.5           85
# 8     8    40    80 brand a  2018         47.5           95
# 9     9    45    90 brand a  2018         52.5          105
#10    10    50   100 brand a  2018         57.5          115
```

### Edit

To replace the values in col1/col2 with the rolling means, instead of adding extra columns, you can use:

```
# Group and calculate rolling means
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(year, brand) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("col"),
         .fns = ~ rollmean(x = .x, k = 4, fill = NA, align = "left"))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly and apparently I was pretty close haha. Tried to give you a plus one, but i'm still too noob to give that to you.... Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `slider` library.  Using data shared by Dr. @jared_mamrot

```r
df <- data.frame(week = rep(seq(from = 1, to = 52, by = 1), times = 4),
                 col1 = seq(from = 5, to = 5 * 52 * 4, by = 5),
                 col2 = seq(from = 10, to = 10 * 52 * 4, by = 10),
                 brand = rep(c("brand a", "brand b",
                               "brand a", "brand b"),
                             each = 52),
                 year = rep(2018:2019, each = 104))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(slider)
df %>% group_by(brand, year) %>%
  mutate(roll_col1 = slide_index_mean(col1, week, after = 3, complete = TRUE),
         roll_col2 = slide_index_mean(col2, week, after = 3, complete = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 208 x 7
#> # Groups:   brand, year [4]
#>     week  col1  col2 brand    year roll_col1 roll_col2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1     5    10 brand a  2018      12.5        25
#>  2     2    10    20 brand a  2018      17.5        35
#>  3     3    15    30 brand a  2018      22.5        45
#>  4     4    20    40 brand a  2018      27.5        55
#>  5     5    25    50 brand a  2018      32.5        65
#>  6     6    30    60 brand a  2018      37.5        75
#>  7     7    35    70 brand a  2018      42.5        85
#>  8     8    40    80 brand a  2018      47.5        95
#>  9     9    45    90 brand a  2018      52.5       105
#> 10    10    50   100 brand a  2018      57.5       115
#> # ... with 198 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>